# having problem with the submit form button with selenium rc and python

Tags: python, ajax, selenium-rc

So i am trying to automate a simple test using selenium rc and python. A Sign Up:

```
   sel = self.selenium
   sel.open("/")
   sel.click("link=Get Started for free")
   sel.wait_for_page_to_load("60000")
   sel.type("full_name", "blah blah")
   sel.type("identity", "blah blah")
   sel.select("gender","label=Male")
   sel.type("password","blahblah")
   sel.wait_for_page_to_load("60000")
   sel.click("xpath=//div[@class='submitWrapper']/input")
   sel.wait_for_page_to_load("100000")
```

i cannot submit the form and it timesout and fails...

anybody have any suggestions on what i could do to make this work

thanks
karen

Answer (score 0):

One reason might be that the page is doing an Ajax call and not a full page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

After the sel.click() what happens on the page?

Answer (score 0):

The second `wait_for_page_to_load` seems suspicious. Usually when you fill out a form, the page doesn't get reloaded - can it be you're running into a timeout and your code doesn't reach the last click (I.e., you're not submitting the form).

In order to check if this is really the problem, I would (for debugging only!) swap the wait with a `time.sleep(10)` and run the script. Another way to check is to run the script with a debugger and "manually" wait and see what's going on.